# Is there a way to change the default mic source system-wide on Android?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, bluetooth-audio, video-recording, audio-recording

I have a bluetooth mic (that can act also as earphones) that I would like to use for recording video from various apps. Most apps don't have an option for using a bluetooth mic source and only use the phone's internal mic, and for certain recording activities I can only use the bluetooth mic. Example apps include Snapchat, Twitch streaming, etc.

Is there some way I can tell the android system to use the connected bluetooth for all mic recording, that all android apps can use? Surely this is a common enough use-case, what with all the bluetooth devices being used, that is should be possible?